# How to map Id property to ClassId with Mapster?

Tags: c#, mapster

I have a 'database' class named User:

```
class SqlUser { public int Id {get;set;} }
```

and a DTO for it:

```
class User { public int UserId {get;set;} }
```

Is there a way to map this automatically using Mapster? It does not work by default.
If it does require configuration, how do I pass the `TypeAdapterConfiguration<T,U>` object to `Adapt` method? It only accept a non-generic `TypeAdapterConfiguration` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass it to `Adapt` method. One option is to call `NewConfig` and `Map`:

```cs
TypeAdapterConfig<SqlUser, User>.NewConfig()
    .Map(dest => dest.UserId, src => src.Id);
var adapt = new SqlUser { Id = 1 }.Adapt<User>();
```

Or use [Prefix/Replace](https://github.com/MapsterMapper/Mapster/wiki/Naming-convention#prefix--replace) approach:

```cs
TypeAdapterConfig<SqlUser, User>.NewConfig()
    .NameMatchingStrategy(NameMatchingStrategy.ConvertDestinationMemberName(name => name.Replace("User", "")));
```